# MySQL query for getting all column names from all tables from a specific DB

Tags: mysql

I would need to find all %phone% instances from all tables in a specific DB.

This is my script i'm trying with yet still getting all the DBs (I need only from DB1):

```
use DB1;
SELECT  *
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    column_name LIKE '%phone%';
```

I also tried writing like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM
    DB1.information_schema.columns
WHERE
    column_name LIKE '%phone%';
```

but I got a `SQL Error [1064] [42000]` for that syntax.

What would be the correct way to query this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database for all the databases on the server. The table database is in the `table_schema` column of the `columns` table.

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'DB1' AND column_name LIKE '%phone%';
```

Comment: So simple and eloquent, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following for '%email%'
and it worked.

So i guess it would for for you too:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE ('%phone%') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='DB1';
```

Answer (score 0):

use the parameter TABLE_SCHEMA, to select your scheam/database

```
SELECT  *
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    column_name LIKE '%phone%'
    AND TABLe_SCHEMA = 'DB1';
```